# how to look up another field in Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Table 1

```
ID
----------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table 2

```
ID                    Desc
------------------------------
A1                    Apple
A2                    Pear
A3                    Orange
```

I am trying to create a Function in Oracle, so that it add the prefix 'A' in Table 1, and after that I want to look up in Table 2 to get the DESC returned. It has to be a function.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Do you want to update a row in `Table 1` and then return the description from `Table 2`? Please also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: ID
----------
Apple
Pear
Orange
4
5

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Replace_Value 
(input_ID IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS

    v_ID varchar(2);
        

BEGIN
        SELECT distinct a.ID
        into v_id
        from Table 2 a
        where  a.ID in (input_ID);
        

   RETURN 
   v_id;

END Replace_Value;

Comment: Please include the code that isn't working in your question and explain what is wrong with it. `where a.ID in (input_ID)` looks a bit suspicious (why not `where a.ID = input_ID`?) but it depends what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following for creation of such a function :

```
Create or Replace Function Get_Fruit( i_id table2.description%type ) 
  Return table2.description%type Is
  o_desc table2.description%type;
Begin
  for c in ( select description from table2 where id = 'A'||to_char(i_id) )
  loop
    o_desc := c.description; 
  end loop;
  return o_desc;
End;
```

where

- no need to include exception handling, because of using `cursor`
  instead of `select into` clause.
- using `table_name.col_name%type` for declaration of data types for
  arguments or variables makes the related data type of the columns
  dynamic. i.e. those would be able to depend on the data type of the
  related columns.
- the reserved keywords such as `desc` can not be used as column names
  of tables, unless they're expressed in double quotes (`"desc"`)

To call that function, the following might be preferred :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2     i_id    pls_integer := 1;
  3     o_fruit varchar2(55);
  4  begin
  5     o_fruit := get_fruit(  i_id  );
  6     dbms_output.put_line( o_fruit );
  7  end;
  8  /

Apple

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with your question- Are you trying to achieve something like this:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Replace_Value 
(
input_ID IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS 
    v_ID varchar(2); 
BEGIN 
    begin
    SELECT distinct a.ID into v_id from Table 2 a where a.ID in (select 'A'||b.id from table1 b where b.id=input_ID); 
    exception
        when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
    end;
    RETURN v_id; 
END Replace_Value;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Yes and no, I am trying to create a function that many Table 1 out there can use this function to get the A prefix and also look up the Desc value given the ID number. That said, I would not know which table name I will be working with, so the query shouldn't contain Table 1 name if that make sense. Thank you

Comment: @JessieWang if you don't have concern about table1 then:- (select 'A'||input_ID from dual)  or  substr(a.ID,2) in input_ID

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying for something like this?

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION replace_value (table_name IN VARCHAR2, 
                                          input_id   IN INTEGER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS 
  v_desc VARCHAR(20); 
BEGIN 
    SELECT descr 
    INTO   v_desc 
    FROM   table2 
    WHERE id  = 'A' || input_id  
           AND ROWNUM = 1; -- only needed if there are multiple rows for each id. 
    RETURN v_desc; 
END replace_value;
```

You may also add an exception handling for `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `INVALID_NUMBER`